# Select friends dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog, multi-friend-selector

How can I select some friends using the Javascript API?

I'm working on a project where I want the user to select some friends which ID's I need, to display their profile images and names (among other things).

How do I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed this...

```
$(".friendSelect").click(function () {
    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', message: 'Choose 9 friends!' }, function (response) {
        console.log(response) //The friends
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) article explains how to get setup and using the Facebook javascript SDK. Once you've got that up and running you will want to get a [FriendList](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/) object. From here you can then get a [User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object for each person in the FriendList.

You may want to try googeling 'javascript graph api tutorial' for code examples

Comment: What I needed was the `apprequests` but didn't know the name for it. Thanks anyway... :-)